# Cannot Get Arch Wifi to Connect

Tags: wifi, archlinux

I cannot get my wifi on my RPI running Arch Linux to connect to my router.

I have had it connected previously, after a lot of messing around (I still don't know what I did to get it to connect though!!)

So now, when I start the RPI and use

```
netctl start wlan0
```

I get an error.  Looking at journalctl -xn I can see

```
-- Logs begin at Thu 1970-01-01 00:00:03 UTC, end at Fri 2016-06-03 20:33:31 UTC. --
Jun 03 20:33:30 alarmpi dhcpcd[1419]: timed out
Jun 03 20:33:30 alarmpi network[1335]: DHCP IP lease attempt failed on interface 'wlan0'
Jun 03 20:33:30 alarmpi kernel: wlan0: deauthenticating from 00:e9:dd:fc:1b:ec by local choice (reason=3)
Jun 03 20:33:30 alarmpi kernel: cfg80211: All devices are disconnected, going to restore regulatory settings
Jun 03 20:33:30 alarmpi kernel: cfg80211: Restoring regulatory settings
Jun 03 20:33:30 alarmpi kernel: cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
Jun 03 20:33:31 alarmpi network[1335]: Failed to bring the network up for profile 'wlan0'
Jun 03 20:33:31 alarmpi systemd[1]: netctl@wlan0.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jun 03 20:33:31 alarmpi systemd[1]: Failed to start Networking for netctl profile wlan0.
-- Subject: Unit netctl@wlan0.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- Documentation: http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/catalog/be02cf6855d2428ba40df7e9d022f03d
--
-- Unit netctl@wlan0.service has failed.
--
-- The result is failed.
Jun 03 20:33:31 alarmpi systemd[1]: Unit netctl@wlan0.service entered failed state.
```

Looks like something to do with dhcp lease????????

Does anyone know what I need to do to correct this?

Thanks

Comment: `alarmpi dhcpcd[1419]: timed out` indicates the problem may be external to the Pi. I was unaware `Arch` used `dhcpcd` (but I don't normally use `Arch`). `dhcpcd` is a new network client which is very robust, and is default in Raspbian for the last year.

Comment: I now have it connected.  Horray!!  I used TimeoutDHCP=30 and it works.  Now the problem I have is that I cannot ping or SSH.  Sounds as if this is a problem with the BT Home Hub 5 perhaps but need to work out what I need to do now.....